# Subsetting a dataset based on a boolean condition assessed on another dataset, keeping the rows that meets the condition (R)?

Tags: r, subset

I have two data frames in which the row names of the first df is in the same order as the column names of the second df.. for example

df1

```
rows something
n1 34
n2 62
n3 15
n4 29
n5 93
```

df2

```
rows n1 n2 n3 n4 n5
r34 2 4 0 0 1
r43 0 5 8 0 2
r75 7 2 5 0 0
```

I have this line of code:

```
df1 = df1[-which(colSums(df2) == 0),]
```

which gets rid of the fourth row in df1..

However I run into the problem of when there is no `colSums(df2)==0`, in that case which returns `integer(0)` and the code doesn't work

Also the line of code also relies on the fact that the row names of `df1` and column names of `df2` are in the same order... which isn't the best assumption to have.

What would be a better way to solve the problem, that is more robust? I presume I need to use `%in%` somewhere...?

Comment: Never trust the `-which()` construction. Always use it as a "positive". This succeeds as intended: df1[ which(1:5 !=4), ]

Comment: Yes it is row.names.. :)

Comment: Not rownames. `which(1:5 !=4) # returns ->
[1] 1 2 3 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try (assuming that `rows` are the `rownames` of the dataset)

```
 df1[colSums(df2)!=0,,drop=FALSE]
 #    something
 #n1        34
 #n2        62
 #n3        15
 #n5        93
```

Suppose, if  colSums are not 0, this gets all the rows,

```
  df2$n4[1] <- 3
  df1[colSums(df2)!=0,,drop=FALSE]
  #    something
  #n1        34
  #n2        62
  #n3        15
  #n4        29
  #n5        93
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(something = c(34L, 62L, 15L, 29L, 93L)),
.Names = "something", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("n1", 
"n2", "n3", "n4", "n5"))

df2 <-  structure(list(n1 = c(2L, 0L, 7L), n2 = c(4L, 5L, 2L), 
                       n3 = c(0L, 8L, 5L), n4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), n5 = c(1L, 2L, 0L)),
                  .Names = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5"), class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c("r34", "r43", "r75"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This variation on akrun's answer would allow having differing orders of cols/rows between df1 and df2:

```
result <- df1[colnames(df2[which(colSums(df2)>0)]),,drop=FALSE]

result
#    something
# n1        34
# n2        62
# n3        15
# n5        93
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of safer alternatives. First, do not use the -which() construction for exactly the reason you illustrate: the no-match case returns an empty vector and the negative of nothing is still nothing. Consider using the logical negation inside the which() argument. Note that you are not actually matching to row names since `which` returns a numeric vector:

```
df1 = df1[ which(colSums(df2) != 0),]  # numerical indexing, not character
#now a vector
```

Or use logical indexing which does not match to rownames:

```
df1 = df1[ colSums(df2) != 0,]  # Logical indexing
# now a vector
```

Could also use that with subset which also preserves dataframe structure:

```
> subset(df1, !colSums(df2) == 0)
   something
n1        34
n2        62
n3        15
n5        93
```

And if you want to keep the dataframe structure using the "]" then add drop=FALSE as a third argument:

```
df1[ colSums(df2) != 0, , drop=FALSE]
   something
n1        34
n2        62
n3        15
n5        93
```